# how can get name of current city in nokia asha java ME

Tags: java-me, nokia, s40

I am working on nokia asha sdk1.1 with using lwuit 1.5.so i want to get the name of current city where user running the app so how i can get it in nokia asha java ME

Answer (score 0):

The phone needs to get this information from somewhere.

So you need to get the current location, and then do something called "reverse geocoding" to get the city for this location.

The nokia developer guide about location may help you:

http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Java/developers-guides/location-services.html